# Where to place common functions for Models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm quite new to Laravel.
I have no DB connection but I'm trying to separate the logic in the Controllers placing it in the Model in order to create fat models and slim controllers.

When doing it I realized I have to make use of common functions in different models. I've seen they usually place those classes in a `app\lib\`, but I guess that's just for controllers to access them? I can not seem to access them from m model:

```
<?php
//in app/lib/MyLog.php
class MyLog{
  //whatever
}
```

Then in m model:

```
//in a model
MyLog::setLogApi($url);
```

The error I'm getting:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyLog' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel\app\models\Overview.php on line 80

Comment: I'm not sure about Laravel 4, but in 5 you have to add a "use App\Mylog;" statement before using it.

Comment: I extend laravel model by Builder class , so it have simple methods for queries, but as own methods are needed, it is good to create own class extend by Builder and thats the class You want to be parent of Your model class. OOP

Answer (score 1):

If you include your Model like this in your Controller `use App\MyLog;`

Then You should have the `MyLog.php` file inside `app\MyLog.php`

**Update :** As the OP wants to access some common functions from any Model

Then [Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators) should help you do that

Here is the similar example given over there

```
public function convertToLower($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['yourLowerString'] = strtolower($value);
    }
```

Comment: What I want to do is use the same functions from my models, not from my controller.

Comment: You want to access the controller from model ?

Comment: No. Access common functions from any model. For example `convertToDecimal($demo)`

Comment: @Alvaro You shall use [mutatotors](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators) to achieve that. Updated in Answer

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your model has a namespacing. If your `MyLog` class has a namespace e.g.:

```
<?php namespace App\Logging;

class MyLog {

}
```

Then you can call that in your controller as follows:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Logging\MyLog as MyLog;

class MyController {
  protected $logger;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->logger = new MyLog;
  }
}
```

It could be possible that you have to do a `composer dump-autoload`. This maps namespaces and classes to the right files.

Comment: I want to call them from my models, not from my controllers

Comment: So you want to call your setter methods in your model? Can you give a usecase as why you would do this? This seems like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: As I'm dealing with the logic in my model I need to call common functions from my models, such as `convertToDecimal($demo)` or `callAPI($params)`. Right now I'm just placing them in a `BaseModel.php` from which all my models extend, but it doesn't seem like a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use namespaces, it's good practice for modern PHP.

File app/lib/MyLog.php

```
namespace App\Lib;
class MyLog {
   // class functions
}
```

File /app/models/Overview.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use App\Lib\MyLog;
class Overview {
    // class functions
}
```

You can use short aliases for fully namespaced classes. Aliases are stored in /app/config/app.php, find part

```
"aliases" => array( 
     'App'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
     .
     .
     . );
```

At the end of array add your new alias for MyLog class:

```
'MyLog' => 'App\Lib\MyLog'
```

And now in your /app/models/Overview.php you can use shorter alias:

```
namespace App\Models;
use MyLog;
class Overview {
    // class functions
}
```